# Группирировать элементы массив по значениям в подмассиве

Tags: php, массивы

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Новые
            [id] => 517
            [name] =>  Маменори Угорь 8 шт 220 гр
            [ingredient_name] =>           Угорь, Манго, Соус Унаги, Сыр Филадельфия, Икра Тобико, Кунжут
            [price] => 119
            [img_full] => https://test-p.joinposter.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Мега роллы
            [id] => 134
            [name] =>  Мега Ролл Сырный с Лососем 10 шт (365гр)
            [ingredient_name] =>  Сыр Филадельфия, Лосось, Огурец, Сыр Чеддер,       Соус Сырный,   Палoчки
            [price] => 137
            [img_full] => https://test-p.joinposter.com/upload/pos_cdb_27367/menu/product_1533715457_134_original.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Бургеры
            [id] => 288
            [name] =>  Черный Бургер "Фитнес"170 гр
            [ingredient_name] => Булочка для бургера, Помидор, Огурец, Салат Айсберг, горчица Французская, Оливковое масло, Соус Мирин,   Ложка в асс
            [price] => 34
            [img_full] => https://test-p.joinposter.com/upload/pos_cdb_27367/menu/product_1522154212_288_original.JPG
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Бургеры
            [id] => 287
            [name] =>  Черный Бургер с лососем с/с 175гр
            [ingredient_name] => Булочка для бургера, Помидор, Огурец, Салат Айсберг,  Лосось, Соус ТарТар для бургера ,  Соусники
            [price] => 64
            [img_full] => https://test-p.joinposter.com/upload/pos_cdb_27367/menu/product_1522154323_287_original.JPG
        )
```

Как я могу объединить элементы массива по `category_name`, либо получить разные массивы для каждого уникального значения в `category_name`?

При выводе должно быть так:

```
Категория: Новые
Маменори Угорь 8 шт 220 гр
Категория: Мега роллы
Мега Ролл Сырный с Лососем 10 шт (365гр)
Категория: Бургеры
Черный Бургер "Фитнес"170 гр
Черный Бургер с лососем с/с 175гр
```

Comment: Используйте [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

Comment: Это называется не `сортировка`, а `групировка`

Comment: @RuslanFree, устраивает вас мое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```
$array = [
    ['category_name' => 'Новые', 'name' => 'Маменори Угорь 8 шт 220 гр'],
    ['category_name' => 'Мега роллы', 'name' => 'Мега Ролл Сырный с Лососем 10 шт 365гр'],
    ['category_name' => 'Бургеры', 'name' => 'Черный Бургер "Фитнес"170 гр'],
    ['category_name' => 'Бургеры', 'name' => 'Черный Бургер с лососем с/с 175гр']
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value['category_name']][] = $value['name'];
}
```

И уже выводим нужный результат на экран:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
{
    echo '* Категория: '.$key. PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
        echo $v . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: А если у меня в массиве будут еще дополнительные ключи, цена и т.д

Comment: @RuslanFree, ну так в чем проблема? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c664092a039489896f99f4c904fc02acc9a5ec9c

Comment: @RuslanFree, получилось?